# Name of a design pattern: Moving data from one language to another

Tags: php, javascript, design-patterns

I'm trying to determine the name of this pattern if it exists. Essentially taking data from one language and using it in another. i.e. PHP -> Javascript. I was thinking it may be delegation, but I've seen this done from time to time, and wanted to know if it was considered a pattern, or is is just a protocol.

**Edit:**
This more clearly defines what I'm talking about. You're not just generating one code or the other, but using it to send values. And so I guess this could be defined as source preprocessing.

```
<?php $foo = $_POST[MY_VAR]; ?>
<script>
    $bar = <?php echo $foo; ?>
    alert($bar)
</script>
```

Comment: How are you getting the data across - JSON or simply outputting the JavaScript vars, etc. via PHP? Either way, I think calling such a thing a design pattern is incorrect, although JSON probably comes close to an XDR in terms of data interoperability.

Comment: an example can be seen here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/javascript-escape/

Comment: That's a great distance from being a design pattern or protocol. You're simply using PHP as a JavaScript generator - nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I updated my answer to cover that possibility. I've done the same thing with JSP and JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

If what you wanted to know is about *communication between processes*, then see sockets, TCP, HTTP and related technologies and data exchange formats like XML, JSON and similar.

If what you want to know is *how to use code written in one language in a program written in another language*, like what .Net or various JVM languages do, then it is interoperability you are talking about. Just keep in mind that in both cases I mentioned, programs in both languages are compiled to a common language (MSIL and Java bytecode, respectively).

In any case, I don't know if this has a name, or even if it is considered a pattern.

EDIT:

Since you specifically mentioned PHP and JavaScript, it is possible that you meant using PHP to generate a JavaScript variable with a literal value, so that you could pass a value from PHP to JavaScript code. This *could* be called **source preprocessing** or maybe **code generation**.

Comment: I think source preprocessing is more of what I was getting at.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the example you link to, that's not a design pattern or protocol and there's no interoperability between PHP and JavaScript whatsoever - the JavaScript interpreter isn't even running as far as PHP is concerned and vice-versa.

You're simply using PHP as a JavaScript **code generator** - nothing more, nothing less.

If you were using JavaScript to extract information in real-time (via "AJAX", etc.) then there would at least be some interaction between the two languages and you could (sort of) consider a data format like JSON (or indeed XML) to be a form of [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation). However, that's not the case in this instance.

Comment: It's not JUST a generator, for instance:

<?php $foo = $_POST[MY_VAR]; ?>
<script>
    $bar = <?php echo $foo ?>;
    alert($bar)
</script>

Comment: @Crewe - That's just code generation. i.e.: It's PHP generating JavaScript. The fact that it's interactively placing the contents of PHP variables into the JavaScript code is irrelevant. (It it wasn't it wouldn't be a code generator - just a means of concatenating chunks of static JavaScript.)

Comment: I see... I guess when I think "code generation" I think entire lines of syntax, not just a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a design pattern at all - well maybe in broader sense than the term is usually used. You basically have two applications talking to each other over HTTP protocol. Languages used are irrelevant.

Comment: True. But it's not really done on a protocol level. It's done where HTML is the medium. and then it's sent over HTTP